# For the iPhone, can you program for different languages?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nlp, ipod-touch

For the iPhone, is it possible to program applications to translate words from a base language to any of several languages of various users. If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, this is called localisation (or as Apple calls it, "internationalization"). Here's [a tutorial](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/), and [here are the Apple docs on it](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get a localized string using `NSBundle` s `-localizedStringForKey:value:table:` for values that you've defined in a localizable.strings file.